# Can I post a job from freelance website into issue queue at drupal.org issue queue list?

Tags: community-official-site

I heard it's kind of illegal to post a paid job request in Drupal.org issue queue. Is it true?

I've emailed the maintainer, but they are busy to do a paid job.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that, since you are asking about posting a request for a paid job in a project issue queue, the paid job is relative to the project. For example, you are willing to pay for adding a feature to the project.

In that case, if the maintainer doesn't have the contact tab accessible to every user, or you don't have any other way to contact him privately, you could open a support request in the project issue queue asking for the availability to do paid jobs, without adding too much details. If the maintainer is available for a paid job, you will get a way to contact the maintainer and provide more details about the paid job you are asking for.

If the request for the paid job is not relative to a project, or the maintainer of the project already answered not to be available for any paid job, you can post on the [Paid Drupal services](https://www.drupal.org/paid-services) forum. Before posting, please see [READ THIS FIRST: Recommendations for hiring a Drupal site developer](https://www.drupal.org/paid-services/2007-11-17/read-this-first-recommendations-for-hiring-a-drupal-site-developer) and [*** RULES FOR THIS FORUM *** read this so your posts don't get deleted](https://www.drupal.org/paid-services/2008-09-15/rules-for-this-forum-read-this-so-your-posts-dont-get-deleted), which contain useful information on how to post a request for paid work.